# To concoct 糟溜鱼片, what lone American alcoholic drink can substitute 米酒, 糟鹵, 花彫, 酒釀?

Tags: substitutions, chinese-cuisine

I travelled prior COVID. This [Hong Kong restaurant](https://www.openrice.com/zh-cn/hongkong/p-%E6%B5%93%E7%9A%84%E9%85%92%E9%A6%99-%E6%9C%89%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%A4%E5%9D%97%E5%B0%91%E5%B0%91%E8%85%A5%E3%80%82%E4%BD%86%E6%95%B4%E4%BD%93%E9%83%BD%E5%87%A0%E5%A5%BD-%E8%8B%8F%E6%B5%99%E6%BB%99-%E5%A4%AA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83-p5933902) served  [糟溜鱼片](https://www.openrice.com/zh/hongkong/p-%E6%A8%82%E5%A4%A9%E7%9A%87%E6%9C%9D-p11931650). I am trying to reconstruct it at home. ***But my American town has no Asian stores, and nowhere sells the 3 Chinese wines listed below.***

**Undeniably, using 1 ingredient is simpler than 3 wines.** *Thus what SINGLE American alcoholic beverage can substitute these three Chinese wines?*

[image]

[image]

http://www.misandao.net/1.%20Chinese%20Food/1.2%20Seafood/WB008.%20FishFilletInWineSauce.htm itemizes 3 Chinese wines:

> 米酒(rice cooking wine) 1大匙 (tbsp)
> 上海老大同香糟卤(rice wine sauce) 75ml
> 酒酿(sweet rice wine) 2大匙 (tbsp)

And [this  chef](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RdvxF0g40U) itemizes 3 Chinese wines too.

> 糟鹵 50克
> 花彫 50克
> 酒釀 15克

Comment: Um ... if they couldn't substitute a single Chinese ingredient, why do you think it would be possible to substitute a single American one?  Often to replace a missing ingredient, you need to combine two or more ingredients to get a similar flavor, acidity, sweetness, etc.

Comment: /Thus what SINGLE American alcoholic beverage can substitute these three Chinese wines?/  PABST BLUE RIBBON!

Comment: Is "rice wine sauce" even an alcoholic beverage, rather than some type of thickened derivation of one?

Comment: Does amazon ship chinese wine?

Comment: @joe i'm just asking! other questions under [substitutions] tag have enquired even weirder substitutions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dry sherry might work. Not certain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).